# send and retrieve variable using POST after insert

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am using php to insert data using in table ***users***.

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (name, social_security_number) VALUES (%s, %s)",
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['social_security_number'], "int"));

    mysql_select_db($database_dbconfig, $dbconfig);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $dbconfig) or die(mysql_error());
    $insertGoTo = "Print.php";
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { 
        $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }

    header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

After insert I redirect to Print.php in order to print a file for that user. I want to send to Print.php ***name*** and ***social_security_number*** using POST.
I am able to do this using GET in Print.php like this:

```
$insertGoTo = "Print.php?ssn=".$_POST['social_security_number'];
```

and in Print.php

```
$find_ssn = $_GET[ssn];
```

**but I will like to have in Print.php**

```
$find_ssn = $_POST[ssn];
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can use `$_SESSION` to send data to next page

Comment: Yes, thank you! I will do this!

Comment: +1 tip: Don't use mysql_* functions, because they're deprecated and they'll be removed. Use mysqli_* or PDO instead.